# Существует в jQuery hasClass() с НЕ ?

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.
Спортивного интереса ради спрашиваю.
Существует ли в jQuery конструкция с отрицанием?

Например, как в php:

```
if(!isset($_GET['blablabla']){...}
```

Только с методом hasClass('red') в jQuery?

```
Ато приходится писать не совсем красивую конструкцию:

if($(this).hasClass('red')){
    //тут пусто :)
}else{
    $(this).animate(...);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вот это жесть))

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('red')){
  // code
}
```

Амфетамины до добра не доведут)

Comment: хы-хы))
точно)

спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с Sh4dow. Для специальных случев в jQuery есть селектор `:not` а также метод фильтрации `.not()`.

Документация:

[:not() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: Предлагаете такое?)

    if ($(this).is(':not([class*="red"])')) { ... }

Ну, если забыть, что фильтруется класс, то да, знать это надо)

Comment: Ну зачем так сложно. Вот так можно: `$(this).not('.red').animate( ... )`. Вообще отпадает необходимость в доп. условии

Comment: а, тоже вариант.
спасибо